# There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system

Tags: php, laravel, logging, gcloud

I deployed a Laravel app on gcloud using the following steps:

`php artisan key:generate --show`

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan view:clear`

`php artisan route:clear`

`gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache`

I have the following in `composer.json`:

```
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "chmod -R 777 bootstrap\/cache",
            "chmod -R 777 storage\/logs",
            "php artisan cache:clear"
        ]
```

`app.yaml` reads as follows:

```
runtime: php72

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: base64:js8r1FFX55XhAcXVjU71plGXGTCt4YrauCqXFHjlsO4=
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: cookie
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
  ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  CLOUDSQL_USER: root
  CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: secret
  CLOUD_SQL_DSN: "mysql:dbname=cbt-sql;unix_socket=/cloudsql/theta-byte-123456:asia-southeast1:cbt-sql"
```

However, I am getting the following error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
(1/1) UnexpectedValueException
There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system

in StreamHandler.php line 172
at StreamHandler->createDir()
in StreamHandler.php line 100
at StreamHandler->write(array('message' => 'There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system', 'context' => array('exception' => object(UnexpectedValueException)), 'level' => 400, 'level_name' => 'ERROR', 'channel' => 'production', 'datetime' => object(DateTimeImmutable), 'extra' => array(), 'formatted' => '[2019-10-12 06:24:56] production.ERROR: There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): There is no existing directory at \\"/workspace/storage/logs\\" and its not buildable: Read-only file system at /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:172)[stacktrace]#0 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php(100): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\StreamHandler->createDir()#1 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(120): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\StreamHandler->write(Array)#2 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(42): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)#3 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(323): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)#4 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(538): Monolog\\\\Logger->addRecord(400, \'There is no exi...\', Array)#5 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(176): Monolog\\\\Logger->error(\'There is no exi...\', Array)#6 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(87): Illuminate\\\\Log\\\\Logger->writeLog(\'error\', \'There is no exi...\', Array)#7 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(539): Illuminate\\\\Log\\\\Logger->error(\'There is no exi...\', Array)#8 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(118): Illuminate\\\\Log\\\\LogManager->error(\'There is no exi...\', Array)#9 /srv/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(37): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler->report(Object(UnexpectedValueException))#10 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(314): App\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler->report(Object(UnexpectedValueException))#11 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(118): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel->reportException(Object(UnexpectedValueException))#12 /srv/public/index.php(59): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\\\Http\\\\Request))#13 {main}"} '))
in RotatingFileHandler.php line 120
at RotatingFileHandler->write(array('message' => 'There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system', 'context' => array('exception' => object(UnexpectedValueException)), 'level' => 400, 'level_name' => 'ERROR', 'channel' => 'production', 'datetime' => object(DateTimeImmutable), 'extra' => array(), 'formatted' => '[2019-10-12 06:24:56] production.ERROR: There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): There is no existing directory at \\"/workspace/storage/logs\\" and its not buildable: Read-only file system at /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:172)[stacktrace]#0 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php(100): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\StreamHandler->createDir()#1 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(120): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\StreamHandler->write(Array)#2 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(42): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)#3 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(323): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)#4 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(538): Monolog\\\\Logger->addRecord(400, \'There is no exi...\', Array)#5 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(176): Monolog\\\\Logger->error(\'There is no exi...\', Array)#6 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(87): Illuminate\\\\Log\\\\Logger->writeLog(\'error\', \'There is no exi...\', Array)#7 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(539): Illuminate\\\\Log\\\\Logger->error(\'There is no exi...\', Array)#8 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(118): Illuminate\\\\Log\\\\LogManager->error(\'There is no exi...\', Array)#9 /srv/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(37): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler->report(Object(UnexpectedValueException))#10 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(314): App\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler->report(Object(UnexpectedValueException))#11 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(118): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel->reportException(Object(UnexpectedValueException))#12 /srv/public/index.php(59): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\\\Http\\\\Request))#13 {main}"} '))
in AbstractProcessingHandler.php line 42
at AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(array('message' => 'There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system', 'context' => array('exception' => object(UnexpectedValueException)), 'level' => 400, 'level_name' => 'ERROR', 'channel' => 'production', 'datetime' => object(DateTimeImmutable), 'extra' => array(), 'formatted' => '[2019-10-12 06:24:56] production.ERROR: There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): There is no existing directory at \\"/workspace/storage/logs\\" and its not buildable: Read-only file system at /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:172)[stacktrace]#0 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php(100): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\StreamHandler->createDir()#1 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(120): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\StreamHandler->write(Array)#2 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(42): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)#3 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(323): Monolog\\\\Handler\\\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)#4 /srv/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(538): Monolog\\\\Logger->addRecord(400, \'There is no exi...\', Array)#5 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(176): Monolog\\\\Logger->error(\'There is no exi...\', Array)#6 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(87): Illuminate\\\\Log\\\\Logger->writeLog(\'error\', \'There is no exi...\', Array)#7 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(539): Illuminate\\\\Log\\\\Logger->error(\'There is no exi...\', Array)#8 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(118): Illuminate\\\\Log\\\\LogManager->error(\'There is no exi...\', Array)#9 /srv/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(37): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler->report(Object(UnexpectedValueException))#10 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(314): App\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler->report(Object(UnexpectedValueException))#11 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(118): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel->reportException(Object(UnexpectedValueException))#12 /srv/public/index.php(59): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\\\Http\\\\Request))#13 {main}"} '))
in Logger.php line 323
at Logger->addRecord(400, 'There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system', array('exception' => object(UnexpectedValueException)))
in Logger.php line 538
at Logger->error('There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system', array('exception' => object(UnexpectedValueException)))
in Logger.php line 176
at Logger->writeLog('error', 'There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system', array('exception' => object(UnexpectedValueException)))
in Logger.php line 87
at Logger->error('There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system', array('exception' => object(UnexpectedValueException)))
in LogManager.php line 539
at LogManager->error('There is no existing directory at "/workspace/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Read-only file system', array('exception' => object(UnexpectedValueException)))
in Handler.php line 118
at Handler->report(object(UnexpectedValueException))
in Handler.php line 37
at Handler->report(object(UnexpectedValueException))
in HandleExceptions.php line 92
at HandleExceptions->handleException(object(UnexpectedValueException))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by following the steps under Set up Stackdriver Logging and Error Reporting at https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard

Comment: Great! I have the same issue. What was your Laravel version?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your application is trying to write logs in the `storage/logs` directory.

This is not allowed, as in the Google App Engine 7.2 environment all directories are read-only, except the `/tmp` directory. Check [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#filesystem_2):

> The runtime includes a writable `/tmp` directory, with all other directories having read-only access. Writing to `/tmp` takes up system memory. For more information, see [tempnam() and sys_get_temp_dir() support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#tempnam_and_sys_get_temp_dir_support).

I have also found [this Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues/777) issue which suggest this to solve it:

> Try adding this to your `app.yaml` under `env_variables`:
>
> ```
> env_variables:  
>   # ...   
>   LOG_CHANNEL: stderr
> ```
>
> Alternatively,
>   follow the instructions later in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard) to integrate with
>   Stackdriver Logging. Either of these should fix your issue.